# Is it safe to wear a down jacket while building a fire?

Tags: clothing, fire, winter-camping

The outside of a down jacket is usually made of nylon or polyester, which is inflammable.

While trying to build a fire, is it safe to wear this jacket? Or will the flying embers be enough to set the person ablaze?

If not, what should the person wear? Fleece?

Comment: Fleece is not that good. I have some burn holes in my fleece jacket from lighting my barbecue...

Comment: @Kaushik: `...a related question, is it possible to get rid of the smoke smell from clothes without actually washing them every single time?` personally I think that should be a separate question. So, I have approved the edit suggested.

Comment: @WedaPashi good idea, though in answer to that try leaving the item on the radiator overnight when it is on - I do this when I get petrol on my woollen gloves and it seems to clear the smell of that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having built several fires while wearing down jackets I can confirm that your jacket will **not** burst into flames, nylon is not that flammable. The worst you will experience is a small burn hole in the outside if an ember lands on you. *Probably still a good idea to keep a safe distance away anyway there are plenty of other ways to burn yourself on a fire.*

Me wearing my down jacket next to a fire (note the lack of flames on my person :) )
[image]

> is it possible to get rid of the smoke smell from clothes without
>   actually washing them every single time?

Air the jacket well (preferably outside) and it should be fine. In my experience down tends to hold the smell less than man made fibres so it should be better with a down jacket than fleece, etc.

Comment: Maybe watch for popping embers too. I've had a couple of red zingers land on nylon and melt little holes through. They can fly a surprising distance.

Comment: `"The worst you will experience is a small burn hole"` Do burn holes in your nice expensive down jackets make anyone else but me cry? I only sit around campfires when I'm wearing my heavy wool or flannel clothes, the whole point of down is to eliminate the necessity of fire in my opinion. Carry a stove and enjoy some hot drinks to warm you up instead of lighting a fire.

Comment: Where on earth did you find chopped wood in a landscape completely devoid of trees? Did you carry that wood all the way to that spot just so you could have a fire?

Comment: The landscape was once well-forested.  Then Liam happened.

Comment: `note the lack of flames on my person` LOL

Comment: [You're the one in green, right?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog)

Comment: Pretty much @ShemSeger. It's not as remote as it looks. About [1/2 hour from the road.](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Unnamed+Rd,+Snowdonia,+Bangor,+Gwynedd+LL57+3LZ/@53.1187524,-4.0243745,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x48650f326f03d385:0xc970f56ac304b41c) I'm also drinking wine.

Comment: @liam: How did Fester know that someone is taking a picture? :D (err, likely to be removed.. 'Too Chatty').. And uintCountSilverBadges++;

Comment: Are those *stairs* cut into the rock?

Comment: Now, it's a built footpath. This is a very, very busy area during the day, lot's a day trippers. So the paths are maintained by the park authority. they have teams of "path builders" and the stones are typically helicoptered up. It prevents the paths from becoming too eroded. Which is a big problem in our little overcrowded country! @ShemSeger

Comment: We can discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) if you like @ShemSeger, though I'm off home soon!

Comment: Um, in my experience down holds smell much more than synthetic fibres, due to the oils they are naturally having. These oils can absorb (and to a certain degree, react with and *become* smoked) much better. It is why fatty meats always smoke better than lean meats/fishes. But a down jacket, having a **windproof shell** should leave the down fairly smokeproof as well.

Comment: It looks like this fire is above timberline.  Shame!

Comment: In the UK we don't really have the concept of timberline, @ab2. We don't have decent forests - they were mostly cut down in prehistoric times. And wildfires are only very rarely a thing here.

Comment: @Rory Alsop If I weren't in my 80s, I'd move there.

Answer (score 15):

In the context of camping, it's perfectly safe to wear a down jacket.  Keep in mind that fleece is typically also made from synthetics, and so can be expected to have similar properties to your down jacket.  (Actually somewhat worse, given the texture.)

A table of synthetic fiber characteristics at http://www.tensiontech.com/tools_guides/burning_characteristics.html provides the following information:

Both nylon and polyester will melt and burn in a flame, but stop burning when removed from the flame.  Polypropylene and polyethylene continue to burn when removed from the flame.

For activities where there is a greater risk of exposure to heat or flame (e.g. hot air ballooning or glassblowing) it's common to require only natural fibers* such as wool or cotton.  This is because synthetics melt as they burn, and can fuse to your skin which increases the severity of the burn.  (Cotton actually has greater flammability than nylon, but has the benefit of not melting.)

Finally, a fabric's characteristics will also affect how it burns.  A looser weave allows greater airflow compared to a thick, dense weave, and a fuzzier surface texture can make it easier for flames to propagate. (Example: using dryer lint for tinder vs. a piece of smooth paper.)  The fabric may also have been chemically treated with flame retardant or DWR coatings.

*Nomex is also useful, but unless someone is a firefighter or race car driver, they are unlikely to have such a suit lying around.

Answer (score 7):

It may be safe for you, but not for your jacket. While it won't instantly burst into flames, your very expensive jacket will get holes melted in it by hanging around a fire, same goes for any other nylons or non fire-resistant synthetic materials. Goose down will burn fairly well, oddly enough there are quite a few youtube videos of people [burning down jackets](https://youtu.be/5ygpdt8nJu0?t=3m24s).

There is a certain romance associated with having a fire, but it will leave you smelling smokey–necessitating extra washings of your delicate gear–and it will damage your technical clothing if a spark or ember lands on you. I used to wear my nice outer layers around campfires until it dawned on me that most of the stuff I have was designed for alpinism, which takes you up above the tree line into areas where there isn't anything to burn. They aren't meant to be worn around a campfire. In fact it's very ineffective to wear a down jacket around a fire because it will actually insulate you against the heat it radiates. Zipping up your jacket and sipping on some hot apple cider, or hot soup will warm you infinitely faster than sitting by the fire will.

Campfire clothes are the heavy **wool** jackets, and **flannel** shirts worn by mountain men, hunters and lumberjacks. I have a wool jacket from nepal that I use as my sit around the fire jacket. Lots of people around here bring their hippie hoodies (aka baja jackets) when they go camping or hang out around a campfire. In scouts, everyone wore their wool scouting blankets like ponchos. First-aid responders will tell you that synthetic materials are actually one of the worst things to have on when working with a fire, because they will melt to your skin if they do catch. There are flame-resistant synthetic materials, Scouts Canada stopped selling wool scout blankets because there had been incidents with boy scouts sitting too close to the fire and setting their blanket aflame, so they started making their blankets out of a flame resistant polyester that feels like thick wool.

Answer (score 2):

I do not necessarily agree with some previous comments.
One one side, embers will typically only burn a hole into your clothes, particularly anything synthetic like polyester or nylon. It does not matter what you are wearing, you may get burn holes. I found cotton or wool the best and hole resistant. Any polyester will get burn holes.

However, the question was related to SAFETY, not being holeproof.

In terms of safety, any puffer jacket made from Pertex, Nylon or Polyester will burn like a torch if the outer fabric catches fire for whatever reason. Polyester will melt, while Nylon will burn. I have tested those two fabrics and compared them. Also both fillings - down or polyester - will burn like a torch; after all, it's combustible material with LOTS of air around it - that's for the insulation after all. Some may remember the fire triangle: fuel/heat/oxygen.
I have tested polyester filling and down and both burn dramatically. Some down is also impregnated against moisture which may or may not contribute to the fire load depending on product or manufacturer.

Why have I done those tests? I will never, ever forget my friend lighting up like a torch when we were kids. He was wearing a puffer jacket and was playing with sticks and fire and some cloth at the end of the stick. He waved it a bit too much and next moment he was in flames.

In short: Puffer jackets are safe if you and the people around you know what they are doing, but a high additional risk if that's not the case and someone does silly things. I hate them for kids around the fire.

Comment: Did someone put the flames out before he was badly burned?

Comment: I guess he was lucky and got away with severe burns in his face only. He survived but the scars never went away. A memory in his face, especially the ears. Think his body was okay as he had some clothes underneath that helped, have no details on that.